# HTML canvas - canvas.context.font resetting

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a simple game in canvas.

http://codepen.io/mrbizle/pen/qZREjN

When I attempt to set canvas.context.font in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop, it is constantly being reset to default values. I am aware that changing canvas attributes such as height and width can reset these values. But I cannot see where I might be doing this.

Relevant functions:

**render.level**

```js
level : function () {
    ctx.font = "Regular 50px Lato";

    console.log(ctx.font); 

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

    ctx.fillText("level", 50, 25);
},
```

**gameLoop**

```js
/**
 * The main loop for the game
 */
function gameLoop() {
    now = Date.now();
    drawTime = (now - lastDrawTime) / 1000.0;

    update.init();
    render.init();

    if(isGameComplete === true) {
        reset();
    }

    lastDrawTime = now;

    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
};
```

`console.log` yielding `10px sans-serif` in google chrome

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to like the `Regular` statement. Remove it and you're done. Ps: FF doesn't like it either btw.

Comment: *facepalm* - the really weird thing is, if you reach the game complete condition, it renders correctly before you resize the window. Any ideas??

Comment: nope, no idea, and I'mnot sure I'm even able to repro

Comment: Hero, thanks for your time.

Comment: Not too sure what is going on but the `FontFace.load` promise seems to be pending all the time even though the font has loaded. To get it to work. don't use the promise just `font.load()` and call `init()` your self, then in the main loop check the `font.status`=== loaded` when true you can then set `ctx.font` without it resetting. It could be code pen, and  issuse 6  in this doc https://drafts.csswg.org/css-font-loading/#issues-index that is causing the pain